# Image is not updating in UI when changing URI at run time using wpf mvvm

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Here is my code

XAML:

```
<Image x:Name="profileimage" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource ProfileViewListboxImagestyle}" Margin="0,10,2,10">
  <Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUri}"></BitmapImage>
  </Image.Source>      
</Image>
```

Model:

```
class Contact
    private Uri _imageUri;
    public Uri ImageUri
    {
      get
      {
        return _imageUri;
      }
      set
      {
        base.Set<Uri>(() => ImageUri, ref _imageUri, value);

        RaisePropertyChanged(()=>ImageUri);
      }
    }
```

ViewModel

```
UpdateImage(Uri uri)
{
  Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
  {
    Contact.ImageUri=uri; //This is not called from UI thread.so i used dispatcher.
  });
}
```

I don't know what is the mistake i have done but i am not getting any error while running this.
Image is not updated in UI but value is updated.
What is the problem?

Comment: why dont you just use `<Image Source={Binding ImageUri}/>` instead of  this `<Image.Source>
    <BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding ImageUri}"></BitmapImage>
  </Image.Source>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As WPF has built-in type conversion from `string` or `Uri` to `ImageSource`, you may simply declare your Image Source binding in XAML like this:

```
<Image ... Source="{Binding ImageUri}" />
```

It is of course also necessary that you set the [source object of the binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#basic_data_binding_concepts). If you do not specify it explicitly in the binding declaration, the `DataContext` of the Image control (or its container) must be set to the `Contact` instance.